# Convert Java 8 Lambda Function to Java 7

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, priority-queue

Hey I'm new to coding and I've kind of gotten a hold of Java 8's Lambda functions but I'm trying to convert some of the code I wrote to Java 7 for a project in school and I can't wrap my head around how to make this piece of code identical in functionality but in java 7. Sorry if this is a dumb questions but I can't seem to figure it out. Do I write a custom method and then apply it to the my PriorityQueue.

```
open = new PriorityQueue<>((Object o1, Object o2) -> {
                Cell c1 = (Cell)o1;
                Cell c2 = (Cell)o2;

                return c1.endCost<c2.endCost?-1:
                        c1.endCost>c2.endCost?1:0;
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use anonymous `Comparator` class here:

```
open = new PriorityQueue<Cell>(new Comparator<Cell>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Cell o1, Cell o2) {
                return c1.endCost < c2.endCost ? -1 :
                        c1.endCost > c2.endCost ? 1 : 0;
            }
        });
```

You can do this automatically in Intellij Idea. Place cursor on `->` and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: I get the following error when I converted my code. "Unchecked Assignment: Java.util.PriorityQueue to Java.util.PriorityQueue<Cell>" Do I need to override the contains method of the PriorityQueue

Comment: @VladislavVaradinov check edits I did - you should use Cell as a generic object here.

Answer (score 5):

Using Eclipse (I don't know about any other IDE), you can do this automatically by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> -> Convert into anonymous class creation

In your case, it's a Comparator:

```
new Compator<>() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        ...
    }
}
```