# How to convert from Java 8 to Java 7

Tags: java

I have to convert this function from Java 8 to Java 7

```
List<LinkBackofficeServiziBean> linkBackofficeServiziBeans = servizi.stream()
                    .map((Integer servizio) -> new LinkBackofficeServiziBean(servizio,userId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How/what have you tried? Do you know what this does? Where does `userId` come from?

Comment: userId come from a front end  message.

Comment: The problem here is that this function need that userId is a final variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536198/convert-java-8-lambda-function-to-java-7

Comment: See the answer given by @ElliottFrisch, but is it really a problem that `userId` has to be (effectively) `final`? Can't you make it `final` in the method? You could post the entire method or a short version of it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Java 8 Lambda Function to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536198/convert-java-8-lambda-function-to-java-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 7 does not have lambdas, easiest way I can see to port this to Java 7 is to instantiate the `List` then use a `for-each` loop to populate it. Something like,

```
List<LinkBackofficeServiziBean> linkBackofficeServiziBeans = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer servizio : servizi) {
    linkBackofficeServiziBeans.add(new LinkBackofficeServiziBean(servizio,userId));
}
```